# Gostaria de editar meu gráfico exibindo um único valor máximo

Tags: r, data, ggplot2, gráfico

Olá pessoal estou com dificuldades em exibir um valor no meu gráfico, é um gráfico da evolução do número de óbitos da minha cidade, meu eixo X é composto por datas de Março até então, e o eixo Y com o número de Óbitos,quando eu utilizei a função geom_text o programa plota todos os valores em todos os seus pontos. Meu objetivo é exibir um único valor, o valor máximo. Eu já tentei de diversas formas mas sempre dá um erro. Vou tentar aqui mostrar pra vocês com mais clareza.

A minha Planilha no excel está da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Abaixo o código que utilizei com geom_text**

```
ObitosSet<- rep(c('date','numeric'),times=c(1,1))
Obitos.Set<- read_excel('OBITOS - 01-09-2020.xlsx', sheet = 2,
                           col_types = ObitosSet)

ggplot(Obitos.Set,aes(Data,Q.Obitos))+
  geom_line(col= "orange", size= 0.7)+
  theme_bw()+
  geom_text(aes(label= Q.Obitos),vjust=-0.5,size=3.5)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits= c(0,12),breaks = seq(from= 0, to= 20, by= 1))+
  labs(x= "",y= "Óbitos",
       fill= NULL,
       title = "Evolução dos casos de Óbitos por mês na cidade de Campina Grande-PB",
       caption = "FONTE: Secretaria Municipal de Saúde, Diretoria de Vigilancia em Saúde - DVS, Setembro de 2020")+
  geom_point(col= "red")
```

[image: Isso foi o resultado]

---

Só que eu quero plotar um único valor, o valor máximo 9, daí to utilizando o seguinte código:

```
ObitosSet<- rep(c('date','numeric'),times=c(1,1))
Obitos.Set<- read_excel('OBITOS - 01-09-2020.xlsx', sheet = 2,
                           col_types = ObitosSet)

p.data<- data.frame(Data=c("2020-06-21"))
p.data$Data<- ymd(p.data$Data)
ValorY<- data.frame(Resp=c("9 (Máximo)"),MaxOb=c(9.5))

ggplot(Obitos.Set,aes(Data,Q.Obitos))+
  annotate("text",x= p.data$Data[2], y= ValorY$MaxOb, label= ValorY$Resp)+
  geom_line(col= "orange", size= 0.7)+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_y_continuous(limits= c(0,12),breaks = seq(from= 0, to= 20, by= 1))+
  labs(x= "",y= "Óbitos",
       fill= NULL,
       title = "Evolução dos casos de Óbitos por mês na cidade de Campina Grande-PB",
       caption = "FONTE: Secretaria Municipal de Saúde, Diretoria de Vigilancia em Saúde - DVS, Setembro de 2020")+
  geom_point(col= "red")
```

Ai dá o seguinte erro:"*Erro: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only*"

Agora interessante é que a função está correta, porque quando eu não específico o tipo de gráfico ele plota, aí quando eu adiciono o tipo de gráfico dá esse erro.

Pessoal sou novo nessa área e já tentei em diversas formas fazer isso, rodei na rede e sempre caio neste erro, ou um erro do tipo POSIXct(Quando eu coloco a função annotate após a função geom_line).

Espero ter sido claro.

Comment: Antes eu tentei o seguinte comando: annotate("text",x= as.Date('2020-06-21'), y= 10, label= "9 (Máximo)"), depois de converter em data com o lubridate, mas tambem me dava os mesmo erros citados acima.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se interpretei bem a pergunta, mas segue uma possível solução:

Código completo:

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- read_excel('./dataset-obitos.xlsx')
df$Data <- as.POSIXct(df$Data, format="%d/%m/%Y")

max_ob <- df %>% group_by(mes = floor_date(Data, 'month'))%>%
  summarise(maximo = max(Q))
        
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Data,y = Q)) +
  geom_line(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = Q), 
            position = position_dodge(width=0.9), 
            vjust = -0.25) 

ggplot(data = max_ob, aes(x = mes, y = maximo))  +
  geom_line(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = maximo), 
            position = position_dodge(width=0.9), 
            vjust = -0.25)
```

Aqui agrupamos pelo mês e sumarizamos com o maior valor encontrado:

```
max_ob <- df %>% group_by(mes = floor_date(Data, 'month'))%>%
  summarise(maximo = max(Q))
```

Saída do primeiro gráfico:
[image: Gráfico 1]
Este mostra todos os óbitos separados.

---

Saída do segundo gráfico:
[image: Gráfico 2]
Este mostra somente os maiores óbitos dentro do mês.

---

Terceiro gráfico:
[image: Gráfico 3]

Este mostra somente o maior número de óbito geral.

Aqui utilizamos annotate:

```
library(readxl)
library(lubridate)

df <- read_excel('./dataset-obitos.xlsx')
df$Data <- as.POSIXct(df$Data, format="%d/%m/%Y")
    
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Data,y = Q)) +
  annotate('text', 
           x = df$Data[which.max(df$Q)],
           y = df$Q[which.max(df$Q)], 
           label = df$Q[which.max(df$Q)], color = 'red')+
  geom_line(stat = "identity")
```

Comment: Eita massa, Fica show também, na verdade eu gostaria de que o gráfico permanecesse o mesmo e no lugar de mostrar todos os valores, mostrar apenas o valor do pico, que foi no dia 21/06/2020 onde teve 9 óbitos. Mas esse também fica show, vlw pela dica.

Comment: Adicionei um novo exemplo somente com o maior número de óbitos.

Comment: Uau! Isso mesmo amigo! Muuuuito obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Caso a resposta seja o que você procurava, considere em marcar como aceita. Isso ajuda as pessoas a visualizarem que a pergunta já foi resolvida e também estimula outras pessoas a responderem suas perguntas. [Veja como](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyLkG.jpg) Abraço!